# Parameters in output in selector, objective c

Tags: objective-c, selector

i'm executing a method in background, by @selector(method) but i dont' understand how can i return data, for example if method name is:

```
-(int)methodWithAge:(int)age
```

i make:

```
int a = [self performBackgroundThread @selector(methodWithAge:) WithObjects:myAge];
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shuold use NSNumber instead of int

```
-(int)methodWithAge:(NSNumber*) age
```

And convert int to NSNumber

```
NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:age];
int a = [self performBackgroundThread @selector(methodWithAge:) WithObjects:num];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using it right. Whats your exact error? I don't know any backin method called performBackgroundThread. You have to pass your values pack to the main thread. Read this [tutorial](http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-keeping-the-ui-responsive-and-a-background-thread-pattern/) on this topic.